# VB6 getting ride of large spaces

Tags: vb6

Hey all, i am trying to replace large spaces between text with just one. My output looks like this right now:

```
5964215">

        This is just the first example of the spaces
    5964478">

        This would be the 2nd example of showing how many spaces this thing has in each sentence.
    5964494">
```

That comes from a textbox that has multi-line to true. Here is what it looks like when it doesn't have multi-line to true.

http://www.june3rdsoftware.com/forums/vb6.jpg

I can not seem to get the spaces to go away! BTW, this text is from a webpage if that makes any difference.

David

Comment: You just want to get excessive blank spaces down to one space?  Have you tried looping through the textbox and replacing spaces?

Comment: Use the regex `s/ +/ /g`. No regexes in VB6? Of course not, it's from 1998. Sigh.

Comment: Why are you still using VB6? VB.NET is so easy to get up and running and you have a huge library at your disposal. At this point it is really naive to be using VB6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the suggestion of MvanGeest, here is some VB code to replace blocks of white spaces:

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As String, y As String
    x = "abcd       defg             1233"
    Dim re As New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "\s+"
    re.Global = True
    y = re.Replace(x, " ")
    Debug.Print y
End Sub
```

To make this work, you will have to add a reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expresssions" to your project.

Comment: So there are regexes in VB6, you'll only have to summon them using a secret incantation. Far short of Perl magic, I admit, but wouldn't it be easier to use a newer programming language (@StealthRT)?

Comment: ... a newer one like Perl, which is from 1987?

Comment: I meant to say that Perl magic is actually much more dark and frightening than what is being applied here. Nonetheless I am a Perl enthusiast and will make a (probably vain) attempt to defend it by saying Perl's "Stable release" field on WP says 2010 while Visual Basic's reads 1998. I don't mean to start a war over this and think everyone should use the language they like, but also to accept that the older a language is, the more difficult seemingly 'simple' tasks become.

Comment: @MvanGeest: thanks for the upvoting, and I should add, I do like Perl more than VB6, too, but I don't like holy wars, either.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no regex support, why not set up a simple state machine that will set the state=1 when a space is found and set state=0 once a non-space is encountered.  You can move char by char when state=0 (thus copying over only 1 space per series of spaces).

Comment: Repeating a false myth over and over again does not make it more true.

Answer (score 0):

Also assuming no regex, you could try something like

```
str = "long       text           with         spaces     "
i = LenB(str)
str = Replace(str, "  ", " ")
Do While LenB(str) <> i
  i = LenB(str)
  str = Replace(str, "  ", " ")
Loop
```

Of course this code could be optimized for long space sequences but it might be all you need as well

Comment: The replace is meant to be str, 2 spaces, 1 space